# **How to solve gmock void signature**

Tags: c++, msbuild, mocking, googlemock

So i got a mock method, with void signature:

```
***MOCK_METHOD(int, GetMaxCrossSectionNumber, (void), (const, override));
```

And it gives me this error:

`This method does not take 1 arguments. Parenthesize all types with unproctected commas`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not pass `void`:

```
MOCK_METHOD(int, GetMaxCrossSectionNumber, (), (const, override));
```